# Finding the number of TCHAR* in TCHAR** . How?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

Here i struck into a challenging case.. I have a C++ code as below

```
  TCHAR **x= NULL;

  x= new TCHAR*[3];

  x[0] = new TCHAR(_tcslen(_T("aaa")));
  x[1] = new TCHAR(_tcslen(_T("bbb")));
  x[2] = new TCHAR(_tcslen(_T("ccc")));
  _tcscpy(x[0],_T("aaa"));
  _tcscpy(x[1],_T("bbb"));
  _tcscpy(x[2],_T("ccc"));
```

I have 3 values Tchars assigned but if i dont know the number of elements that "x" contains(may be it have some 10 strings) .. how can i get the exact number of elements..??

If it is a 2D array i can know by

```
 result = (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]));
```

So it will show me the number of rows in it (as in the example i will get 3 as result).. But here is there any way to get the number of strings ?

Comment: Use a vector and choose `char` or `wchar_t` depending on whether you want to support Windows 9x (hint: just use `wchar_t` if you're planning on these going into Windows API functions), then change `TCHAR *` to `std::[w]string`. Right now, you're not even using the pointers correctly. For example, you allocate *one* `TCHAR` with the value `_tcslen(_T("aaa"))` and so forth. Even if you allocated an array, it would be too short for what you copy in.

Comment: TCHAR is just one char, isn't it?

Comment: @NeilKirk TCHAR is a macro that changes depending on if UNICODE is defined. It's 16 bits if UNICODE is define, 8 bits otherwise.

Comment: @RobK But does it expend to `char *` for example or just `char`. This was my point. It looks he wants to store a whole string in one character. But I could be wrong as I haven't used this before.

Comment: @NeilKirk, It's a dynamic array of strings. One pointer for the "array" and one for the string.

Comment: To do this dynamically, create a 4th element and put a `NULL` pointer there. So you can use the `NULL` as indicator for the lists end.

Comment: @NeilKirk `TCHAR` it expands to either `char` or `wchar_t`

Comment: Ah, did he mean `new TCHAR[_tcslen(_T("aaa"))];` instead?

Comment: @NeilKirk probably that, with `+1` !

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't. The proper way to deal with this code is to format the disk it lives on, then smash it with a brick for a good measure. Use std::vector and std::string

Comment: Do not use `TCHAR` unless you are porting ancient windows APPs (pre-NT) to new windows. Even though MSDN uses it and derived types for prototypes and explanation, that's just to avoid mentioning both the Ansi and Wide versions separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to know how many items are in an array if you only have a pointer to one of the items.

You will need to remember this information via another variable, or a sentinel value at the end of the list. Preferably wrapped up in a unit that contains the pointer and a function that knows how to find the length.

Chances are that other improvements to memory management can be made in your code too, there's pretty much no reason to use `new` for strings.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::vector<std::basic_string<TCHAR>>`. This will automatically keep count of the strings, their lengths, how many there are, and when to free them. You cannot know how many items are in an arbitrary array after the fact given a pointer to one random element.

Also, the whole `TCHAR` thing, really? That stuff is from like, 20 years ago. Everybody uses Unicode now.

Answer (score -1):

You can use NULL-pointer arrays (plain C style) or std::vector. Speaking about NULL-pointer arrays...

```
TCHAR **x= NULL;

x= new TCHAR*[4];

x[0] = new TCHAR[_tcslen(_T("aaa"))+1];
x[1] = new TCHAR[_tcslen(_T("bbb"))+1];
x[2] = new TCHAR[_tcslen(_T("ccc"))+1];
x[3] = NULL;
_tcscpy(x[0],_T("aaa"));
_tcscpy(x[1],_T("bbb"));
_tcscpy(x[2],_T("ccc"));

int size=0;
TCHAR ** y = x;
while(*y++)  size ++;
printf("Array size is: %d", size);
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `TCHAR[_tcslen(_T("aaa")) + 1];`

Comment: yes, of course. Original code will definetely lead to segfault :)
fixed answer.